How do I pass a pointer (to an int) into a function using PyObjC in Python?
Take the IORegistryEntryCreateIterator function as an example.
The final argument of the function is a pointer to an io_iterator_t (which is just an alias for a uint32). I am not sure how to accomplish this via PyObjC in Python, and am having trouble finding anything useful in their documentation.
I tried passing in  CTypes, both byref and pointer, but that doesn't work. In both cases, you get a ValueError when depythonifying. And of course, passing in a plain non-pointer int doesn't work either.

Is there a pyobjc-framework for IOKit?
